# CodeIgniter pagination won't go past first page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a blog page of posts that I am trying to paginate using CodeIgniter. The numbering and limiting seem to be working fine, except I keep getting a 404 when I try to travel to another page.

The strange thing is the normal culprits that cause this issue are correct. The baseUrl and the uri_segment.

My controller looks like this:

```
$config                = array();
$config["base_url"]    = $this->config->site_url("/blog");
$config["total_rows"]  = $this->blog_model->count();
$config["per_page"]    = 2;
$config["uri_segment"] = 2;
$config["num_links"] = round($config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"]);

$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

$this->load->view('blog', array(
    'user' => $this->user,
    'blog' => $this->blog_model->loadPosts($config['per_page'], $page),
    'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
    'footer' => $this->blog_model->loadFooter()
));
```

And then in my model I am grabbing the posts

```
public function loadPosts($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by("date", "desc");
    //this loads the contact info
    $query = $this->db->get('entries');
    return $query->result();
}
```

My full URL is `www.mysite.com/blog` and then with the pagination it appears as `www.mysite.com/blog/2`.

For the base_Url I have also tried `base_url() . "/blog";`.

And I have tried setting the uri_segment to 1 and 3, but nothing seems to work.

As well I have tried playing around with the routing and have added just to see if it would do anything:

```
$route['blog/(:num)'] = 'blog/$1';
```

Comment: You don't need to use uri->segment. Set a parameter in your controller function, it will take the value of your segment. e.g. function example($page = 0). No error possible that way. Also, remove your route rule as it does nothing and may be tricky later.

Comment: @AdrienXL I was at the point of trying anything with the route. I've already disabled it once I saw it did nothing. I've always had to set a uri_segment and I've read many articles that state without it the pagination will not work at all. How would I set it up in the controller without using it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this line of code if your code is inside the index method:

> $route['blog/:any'] = "blog/index/$1";

Because you have used the ***segment(2)***, and you should change the **blog/index/$1** to **blog/:any**.

Comment: This is wrong answer. `blog /abc` will redirect to index function.but it seems it should redirect `abc` function.only for numbers it should redirect index function. and also `$1` used unnecessary and wrong way.

Comment: Try to use `example.com/blog/test`.It will execute the `index` function not `test` function. Also you used $1 wrong way.look here https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html  how to use $1,$2

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the function name that contain your pagination code is index(), you should change the route to:

```
$route['blog/(:num)'] = 'blog/index/$1';
```

And in your index() function, add the $page parameter:

```
public function index($page = 1){
...
```

Comment: I got rid of the index with the .htaccess would I still have to change the route? Where would I call the $page variable after I pass it to the function?

Comment: instead of  `$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;`use the one given in the parameter

Comment: Ok, cool. I used the route and that seemed to fix the not found (Thank you!), but I am still confused about the $page. When I use that $page the next page gives me back the same results as the first page.

Comment: if so then I guess your first page isn't 1 it's 0 ($page = 0)

Comment: Also `$config["uri_segment"] = 2;` should be changed as `$config["uri_segment"] = 3;`

Comment: When I change it to uri segment to 3 it completely breaks. Also $page setting to 0 made no difference. It's just showing the same results.

Comment: The url is changing to blog/1 and blog/2, but the posts are showing the same on each page.

Comment: Try a `var_dump($page)` in your `index()` function and check if the value is changing

Answer (score 3):

With your routes, try if you can to add as many `:any`s or `:num`s after as you like:

```
$route['blog'] = 'blog/index'; // For the first level
$route['blog/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'blog/index/$1/$2'; // For extra "uri" segments.

// base_url pagination

$config["base_url"] = base_url("blog"); // Is preferred
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a parameter to the index() function of a controller like it is a random function.

If you try to do controller/var instead of controller/function/var, CodeIgniter will search for a function var() inside the controller which does not exists. That's what happen when you try to access `blog/2`: `2()` isn't a function in your controller.

You can create a new function in your controller, let's say page(), and move your code inside. That way, you will call `blog/page/2`. Function `page()` will exists and will not get a 404. Also don't fordet to redefine your base_url for pagination.

```
$config["base_url"] = site_url("blog/page");
```

Another solution if you absolutely need the URL like `/blog/2`, routes:

```
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'blog/index/$1';
```

Remap may also be a solution: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Comment: So, if I'm understanding this correctly, you want me to move all my code out of the index and put it within a function and then call the function within index?

Comment: @zazvorniki; not really, In the answer above, I explain you can move the code currently inside index() to an new function and use that function instead of index(). As an alternative solution, you can use routes in order to  send parameters to the index function. That's what you are currently trying to do without success.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your other code as it is. Just add this at your routes.php file:

```
$route['blog/:num'] = "blog/index";
//Assumes your code is inside the index method.
//If not, use this way:
//$route['blog/:num'] = "blog/YOUR_METHOD_NAME";
```